# if then statement not working and crashes

Tags: if-statement, parseint, action-button

Been trying to get my code to work but it seems to comes crashing. 
Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance :-)

```java
EditText HbA1c;
TextView result;
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    HbA1c = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.HbA1c);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
}


public void onButtonClick(View view) {
    int num = Integer.parseInt(HbA1c.getText().toString());

    if (HbA1c == 6.5) {
        result.setText("DM");
    } else {
        result.setText("not DM");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this question is quite incomplete; classical mantra is "what did you want to achieve, what you did, what you expected to happen, what actually happened". We have here only what you did and quite vaguely what happened (what were the error messages?), but not the rest.

Comment: [@alchemist21](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9365023/alchemist21) it's probably `if (num == 6.5)` and `double num = Double.parseDouble(HbA1c.getText().toString())`

Comment: the error messages were incomparable types: EditText and double then MyOnClickListener is not abstract and does not override abstract method onClick(View) in OnCLickListener

Comment: Thanks. got the if then statement but my code still crashes after execution